# Spree Why there is a Taxonomy and a Taxon model

Tags: spree

I am reading the spree code source and I am wondering why there is a model Taxon and a model Taxonomy.

According to the Spree documentation:

- Taxonomy – a hierarchical list which is made up of individual Taxons.
- Taxon – a single child node which exists at a given point within a
  Taxonomy. Each Taxon can contain many (or no) sub / child taxons.

As Taxon can have many taxons and taxons can have children. Why there is a need of the Taxonomy model? Is this due to performance?

(NOTE: I am not sure this is the right place to ask as it's not really code related issue)

Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A taxonomy is representative of the root node. It provides the over-arching classification for a set of items. For example, "Clothing" could be a taxonomy (with a root "Clothing" *taxon*) and then underneath that root there would be other taxons like "Pants", "Shirts", "Shoes" and so on.

There's no particular reason why we have both taxonomies and taxons other than that's the way it's always been and to change it right now does not leads to any particular benefit.

Comment: is there a way to add a product to have a taxonomy? or just taxons?

Comment: A product can only have taxons.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with Spree in a while, but if i remember correctly, then `Taxonomy` represents an entire tree, whereas `Taxon`s are the nodes that make up that tree.

Comment: Hi Marian. Thanks for your answer. In fact that's right, but If you create taxon children of a first root taxon, this root taxon is the entire tree, and the first level taxons are tree itself... So I still don't understand why having 2 models for this. :-(

Comment: I know, and this fact bothered me back then, when we worked with spree. One could argue that there are certain properties to associate with the entire tree (and are therefore columns in the taxonomies table) that make no sense for individual nodes. Nevertheless, the data model is not quite perfect. If you're lucky, someone from the Spree core team reads this and can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Those two things confused me also. I guess the reason that taxononies exist is for speed. Each taxon has taxonomy_id and it helps to find a taxon within a taxonomy hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this is that a product can have more than one taxon. This way for example a product can have a brand taxon and a range taxon and a size taxon on a color taxon (assuming not set as a variant), allowing multiple selection pathways for a product.